# Direct sum of two sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ be two sheaves on $X$  ,is
$ H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}_1 \oplus \mathcal{F}_2) \simeq 
H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}_1) \oplus H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}_2)  $ ?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I proof that there is  an  injective morphism from $H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}_1) \oplus H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}_2)$ to $ H^{i}(X,\mathcal{F}_1 \oplus \mathcal{F}_2)$